My GCP project doesn't allow the Snowflake service account to connect
This new GCP policy doesn't allow my Snowflake account service account to connect: iam.allowedPolicyMemberDomains.

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains

When I try to add the Snowflake service account it gives me an error like this:

Policy update failed: A domain restriction organization policy is in place. Only members of allowed domains can be added as memebers of the policy. Correct the member emails and try again.

What can I do about this?

The GCP docs list a solution with the title "Linking Google Analytics 360 with BigQuery" as even their own products have this problem with this policy:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains#linking_360_with

The steps are to turn off the policy, add the service account, turn on the policy again. Quoting the docs:


Disable the organization policy containing the domain restriction constraint.
Do the linking process in Google Analytics 360.
Enforce the domain restriction constraint again.


There might be more steps needed to specifically whitelist Snowflake's service account - and the Snowflake docs will keep the specific values for DISPLAY_NAME, DIRECTORY_CUSTOMER_ID, Project id and Project number at:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-gcs-config

